# Insert datepicker yii2

Tags: yii2

In table I have a columns where data like `2016-12-13 10:51:03` which output in gridview. I put datepicker

```
[
          'attribute'=>'order_statusUpdatedAt',
          'value'=>'order_statusUpdatedAt',
          'format'=>'raw',
          'filter'=>DatePicker::widget([
          'model'=>$searchModel,
          'attribute'=>'order_statusUpdatedAt',
          'clientOptions'=>
             [
              'autoclose'=>true,
              'format'=>'yyyy-mm',
             ]
    ]),
],
```

I want to search all lines which have like 2016-12. How could I search for partial matches?

OrderSearch

`public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Order::find();
        // add conditions that should always apply here

```
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
```

'order_createdAt' => $this->order_createdAt]);

```
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to search in?

Comment: @SiZE in gridview.

Comment: where is you r searchModel code?

Comment: @MohanPrasad add to question

Comment: you want to search based on the date 2016-12? Mean to say when you enter the date 2016-12 you need to get all the data which has 2016/12?

Comment: @MohanPrasad yes, when i enter 2016-12, i want to get all data wich include 2016-12, this 2016-12-15 14:52:25 and this 2016-12-11 23:07:04 true data. this is not 2016-10-11 23:00:04

Comment: So you want to filter according to year and the month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your grid conditions add this bit of code.

```
 $query->andFilterWhere(['like','order_createdAt', $this->order_statusUpdatedAt]);
```

the third condition should be the attribute where you have specified in your search field attribute. So the search data you entered in the search field will be like the data from your database, i.e. 'order_created' in your case.

Hope this helps you..